# Android Intent Phone Call

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to make phone call through an app in android which will not show display. Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);         intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+XXX"));         intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 0);
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
 {      // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions             
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding                 //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,             //                                          int[] grantResults)             // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation             // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.             return;         } 
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);     
}
```

and this error is shown:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?  (Target SDK = 22)

```
String phone = [phone number];    

Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));

[context].startActivity(localIntent);
```